# Retreiving data from nested stackpanels

Tags: stackpanel

Would you be able to help with how I can access the text boxes from nested stackpanels for writing back to my source xml.

I'm dynamically creating stack panels as it makes it easier to display and because the results can be 1 line or 50 lines.
The source is an XML file that's been deserialised, but I only need to deal with 1 section of this which is Children[7], this is always fixed.

Once written out to the stackpanel the idea is a user can adjust the text in the textbox and then I can read it back and adjust the XML source appropriately.

Here's how I'm populating the stackpanels, but as you can see there are multiple Instances, so multiple stackpanel children:

```
XmlDoc = Deserialize();
if(XmlDoc != null)
{
    var docWindow = new Window();
    docWindow.Width = 900;
    docWindow.Height = 600;
    var stackPanelMain = new StackPanel { Orientation = Orientation.Vertical, Margin = new Thickness(10,10,10,10) };
    stackPanelMain.Children.Add(new Label { Content = XmlDoc.Sections.Field.Children[7].Name, FontSize = 20 });
    foreach(var value in XmlDoc.Sections.Field.Children[7].Instances)
    {
        var stackPanel = new StackPanel { Orientation = Orientation.Vertical };
        stackPanel.Children.Add(new Label { Content = value.Children[0].TextValue.Text });

        var stackPanelFields = new StackPanel { Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal };
        stackPanelFields.Children.Add(new TextBox { Width = 200, Height = 40, Text = value.Children[1].TextValue.Text});
        stackPanelFields.Children.Add(new Image { Width = 200, Height = 40 }); // yet to be created
        stackPanelFields.Children.Add(new TextBox { Width = 200, Height = 40, Text = string.Format("{0}/{1}/{2}", value.Children[2].TextValue.Text, value.Children[3].TextValue.Text, value.Children[4].TextValue.Text) });
        stackPanelFields.Children.Add(new Image { Width = 200, Height = 40 }); //yet to be created

        stackPanel.Children.Add(stackPanelFields);
        stackPanelMain.Children.Add(stackPanel);
    }               
    docWindow.Content = stackPanelMain;
}
```

After a user has adjusted the text I need to write it back to the xml file so iterate through all the text boxes, and start writing the values back.
This is where I'm stuck on how to access all the textboxes from all the children, I was looking at something like this:

```
int xmlInstance = 0;
foreach (var tb in stackPanelMain.Children.OfType<TextBox>())
{
    XmlDoc.Sections.Field.Children[7].Instances[xmlInstance].Children[1].TextValue.Text = tb.Text;
    XmlDoc.Sections.Field.Children[7].Instances[xmlInstance].Children[1].TextValue.IsVerified = true;
    xmlInstance++;
}
```

But that's only dealing with 1 child.

How can I access all child textboxes in the stackpanels? Or indeed if there is a better way to display and retrieve back this data I'd much appreciate a pointer.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Think I may have found the answer finally on here, took some searching but this is working for me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17745505/wpf-c-sharp-finding-controls-from-panel-inside-a-panel/17750097#17750097

Answer (score 0):

My continued searching found the answer in this post: [WPF C# Finding controls from panel inside a panel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17745505/wpf-c-sharp-finding-controls-from-panel-inside-a-panel/17750097#17750097)

My Thanks to whoever Dick Schuerman is, but it worked perfectly!

```
 class ChildControls
    {
        private List<object> lstChildren;

        public List<object> GetChildren(Visual p_vParent, int p_nLevel)
        {
            if (p_vParent == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("Element {0} is null!", p_vParent.ToString());
            }

            this.lstChildren = new List<object>();

            this.GetChildControls(p_vParent, p_nLevel);

            return this.lstChildren;

        }

        private void GetChildControls(Visual p_vParent, int p_nLevel)
        {
            int nChildCount = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(p_vParent);

            for (int i = 0; i <= nChildCount - 1; i++)
            {
                Visual v = (Visual)VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(p_vParent, i);

                lstChildren.Add((object)v);

                if (VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(v) > 0)
                {
                    GetChildControls(v, p_nLevel + 1);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

And you use it like this:

```
    ChildControls ccChildren = new ChildControls();

foreach (object o in ccChildren.GetChildren(WrapPanelTest, 5))
{
    if (o.GetType() == typeof(TextBox))
    {
        // Do something
    }
}
```